# What is the importance of singularities of type II in the Mean Curvature Flow?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, flows

I am reading the Mean Curvature Flow and Isoperimetric Inequalities by Manuel Ritoré, Carlo Sinestrari, Vicente Miquel and Joan Porti and I am curious to know what is the importance in understand the singularities of type II in the Mean Curvature Flow.

Thanks in advance!